# Not able to remove caption shortcode from the content

Tags: php, theme-development, themes, shortcode, captions

```
[caption id="attachment_6" align="alignright" width="300"]...Some Text...[/caption]
```

I am unable to remove caption shortcode from the content of the post. I have tried using `strip_shortcodes()` and and I also used RegEx to remove the shortcode but neither worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove shortcode"? to remove shortcode - just use `remove_shortcode('caption');`. Or you want to keep shortcode in content but it should do nothing with your text?

Comment: What I want is that the caption (...Some Text...) should remain there but the tags ([caption id="attachment_6" align="alignright" width="300"]  [/caption]) should not appear.